# How to scroll in the nested grid div?

Tags: html, css, grid

please have a look [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/myxnc9rg/7/), which I cannot make the nested `div #2.2` scrollable. Can anyone help it out? Thank you.

For this layout, there is a root grid div containing two divs (`div #1` and `div #2`). Inside `div #2` grid div, there is two divs (`div #2.1` and `div #2.2`). The `div #2.2` is an oversized yellow div which I want to scroll, but I cannot.